# What is the best way to phrase this?

Tags: phrases

I would like to say something along the lines of "as certain as I am that this is the right move for me personally, I am also certain that this is the right move for your company". What is the best way to phrase this?

Comment: It seems to me you have some good phrasing there already.  Or Jackyef's answer without "the" before "both.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this move will benefit the both of us.

Comment: “The both of us” seems colloquial.   “is mutually beneficial”

Comment: @Jim always better to be colloquial rather than formal in all but legal cases these days... my opinion at least... although I'd scratch the "believe" and input a "I'm sure"